# Run length encoding, how do I remove the '1' before characters that appear only once?

Tags: java

I have a homework problem that involves using Run Length Encoding. The problem is, we're NOT allowed to put a '1' before any character that only appears once. For example, if you input AAABBC, I'll get 3A2B1A, but I need to get 3A2BA. Is there a simple fix to this that I'm missing?

Here's my current code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input:");
        String s = scanner.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0, count = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (i + 1 < s.length() && s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i +1))
                count++;
            else {
                string = string.concat(Integer.toString(count))
                        .concat(Character.toString(s.charAt(i)));
                count = 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: in your `else`, check whether `count` is 1, and do different things based on whether it is or not.

Comment: Additionally: don't use `concat`. Use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your description. I think it should be 3A2BC. Nevertheless, I would split the string creation. Put the integer part in an if-else and concat the number only if count is >1

Answer (score 0):

Just add a little extra logic to not print the count if it be 1:

```
for (int i=0, count=1; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (i + 1 < s.length() && s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i+1)) {
        count++;
    }
    else {
        String prefix = count > 1 ? Integer.toString(count) : "";
        string = string.concat(prefix)
            .concat(Character.toString(s.charAt(i)));
        count = 1;
    }
}
```

As a side note, you should use a `StringBuilder` instead of raw string concatenation (though Java might automatically choose to do this under the hood for you anyway).

If you want to stick with your exact current implementation, then here is a one-liner regex cleanup you could try:

```
string = string.replaceAll("(?<=(?:\\D|^))1(?=\\D)", "");
```

Comment: "Java might automatically choose to do this under the hood" it *might*; but since it is less verbose to use `StringBuilder.append` (it has overloads for `char` and `int`, which also avoid explicit string creation), you may as well use it directly.

Comment: @AndyTurner I was in no way advocating _not_ to explicitly use `StringBuilder`.  Just saying that not doing so is less evil now than it was 10 years ago on, e.g. Java 5 or something.

Comment: In fact, Java will *not* use `StringBuilder` under the hood. It constructs a new String by concatenating the underlying arrays. So it is *less* efficient than using `+` to concatenate strings, because then it will create and dispose of a `StringBuilder` for every expression instead of every concatenation (an expression here would contain two concatenations). Using a `StringBuilder` manually means you only create and dispose of one instance.